# Distinguish browser tab closed and browser closed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework, frameworks

I would like to distinguish two cases in my browser

1) tab browser is closed
2) browser is closed

It's possible? I read about onunload but it doesn't work. I know that it's the same for this two cases. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: only if you had another tab in the same browser: it they close together, it's likely the browser, just one and it's a tab for sure.

Comment: I don't understand.. I'm talking about distinguish this cases in code like PHP, Jquery or other language whose can be communicated with this technologies.

Comment: It's not that simple because browsers do not all support 'closing' tabs and windows in the same way. It is very unreliable.

Comment: well, like i said, it's possible to detect in js, but i don't think that it's useful because you don't have much time to do anything about it. for php, you can try to use img pings to hit your server onunload, but they moght not make it before the browser closes. same with localStorage: it often "doesn't make it" before the window closes. if you don't need the info then and there, you would have more luck saving to and fetching it from cookies upon the next page visit. if that even helps...

Comment: i was thinking of saving cookies but i don't know how i can delete cookies only when browser is closed, it's possible?

I'm trying with user activity check in regular intervals but it gave poor results because users with bad internet connection were often kicked (all working on socket.io)